# How do I override git command?

Tags: git

when I set `git config --global alias.pull 'pull --rebase=merges'`  , it seems like `git pull` does not do a rebase, it tells "Not possible to fast-forward, aborting".

maybe I can use another world instead of pull, but I used to using this word

Comment: have a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase

Comment: It's unclear whether answers are supposed to address the particular issue of specifying the default pull action (which is possible without using an alias), or to explain how aliases work in general.

Comment: @mkrieger1 and either way it would be a duplicate

Comment: @LiuHao : you cannot override a built in command with an alias, git prevents you from doing this. As indicated by DanielAWhite, you can set a config parameter for git pull.

Comment: Note that while the alias itself is ignored, the error you're getting could be due to a bug in the Git version you're using. Update and set `pull.rebase` to `merges` (`git config --global pull.rebase merges`) and the problem should go away in a current Git.